# Java-based regular expression to allow alphanumeric chars and ', and 

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to regular expressions in Java and I need to validate if a string has alphanumeric chars, commas, apostrophes and full stops (periods) only. Anything else should equate to false.

Can anyone give any pointers?

I have this at the moment which I believe does alphanumerics for each char in the string:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\s]{1," + s.length() + "}");
```

Thanks

Mr Albany Caxton

Comment: why don't you test it yourself?

Comment: check this link, http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/UseMatcherappendReplacementtomatchazAZ09.htm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *I'm new to regular expressions in Java and I need to validate if a string has **alphanumeric chars**, **commas**, **apostrophes** and **full stops** (periods) only.*

I suggest you use the `\p{Alnum}` class to match alpha-numeric characters:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Alnum},.']*");
```

(I noticed that you included `\s` in your current pattern. If you want to allow white-space too, just add `\s` in the character class.)

From [documentation of `Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> [...]
>
> `\p{Alnum}` An alphanumeric character:`[\p{Alpha}\p{Digit}]`
>
> [...]

---

You don't need to include `^` and `{1, ...}`. Just use methods like `Matcher.matches` or `String.matches` to match the full pattern.

Also, note that you don't need to escape `.` within a character class (`[`...`]`).

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\s\\.,]{1," + s.length() + "}$");
```

Comment: Gives illegal escape character.

Comment: Sorry, each backslash should be doubled, otherwise it will be illegal, that's true.

Comment: Think it should be: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\s\\.',]{1," + s.length() + "}$");

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
String x = "some string";
boolean matches = x.matches("^[\\w.,']*$");
```

Comment: No need to include `^` and `$` for `matches`.